# Spelling Suggestions / Spellchecker in Android

Tags: java, iphone, android, dictionary

I want to implement word suggestion for miss-spelled words in Android. So looking for some library like `UITextchecker` or `NSSpellchecker` in iPhone where we call `guessesForWordRange` to get the spelling suggestions.

I have searched on Google and see many people stating that there is no such feature provided in Android till now, if so, what is the best Java library or any workaround to implement this?